# How to combine two queries result of different tables into one query in Parse?

Tags: javascript, parsing, parse-platform

I am trying to use relational query here . I have 'Post' table and 'Comment' table. I want all the comments having post_id from the Post table and also all the post related to that post_id from Post table. I have made post_id pointer here.  As far, what I have done is I am able to get comments having that post_id, but I am not able to get post from that Post table using that post_id. Here, is what I have done so far :

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("getAllPost", function (request, response)
{           
  var Post = Parse.Object.extend("mst_Post");
  var Comment = Parse.Object.extend("mst_Comment");
  var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Post);
  innerQuery.exists("objectId");

  var query = new Parse.Query("mst_Comment");
  query.matchesQuery("post_id", innerQuery);
query.find
({
  success: function(result) 
  {
      response.success(result);
  }
});
```

How do I get posts also using this, containing that same post_id from the Post table. Any help would be appreciated .Note : Please don't suggest query.or , as it takes data from the same table only, and in my case there are two different tables.  Note :

```js
error : code": 141,
    "error": "Error: Tried to encode an invalid date.  for (j = 0; j < commentResult.length; j++) 
                        {
                            var comment_post_id = commentResult[j].get("post_id").id;
                           var comment_date = commentResult[j].createdAt;  
                            var extract_Date =new Date(comment_date.iso) 
                            var comment_id = commentResult[j].id;
                            if (comment_post_id == post_id) {
                                var tempArr = {
                                    comment_id : comment_id,
                                    comment: commentResult[j].get("comment"),
                                    comment_location: commentResult[j].get("comment_location"),
                                    Comment_Date :  extract_Date
                                }
                                commentArr.push(tempArr);
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Summarize what you want.

You want to get comments and its post.
Every comment have a pointer named 'post_id'

Just using include, so that parse will get related post data inside the related field.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getAllPost", function (request, response)
{           
  var Post = Parse.Object.extend("mst_Post");
  var Comment = Parse.Object.extend("mst_Comment");
  var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Post);
  innerQuery.exists("objectId");

  var query = new Parse.Query("mst_Comment");
  query.matchesQuery("post_id", innerQuery);
  query.include("post_id");
query.find
({
  success: function(result) 
  {
      //console.log(result[0].get('post_id').get('XXX in post'));
      response.success(result);
  }
});
```

reference 
https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-relational-queries

---

***Updated Part***

If you want to get createdAt of Paras.Object, just use **obj.createdAt** not use obj.get("creadtedAt").

If you want to transform the result to Date type,

new Date(obj.get("Comment_Date").iso)

the String in Comment_Date.iso is convertable to Date Object

Comment: Hi ChunTIngLin, Thanks for your answer. As suggested by you, I have used include in my code. It is giving me records but not as I wanted. Actually , I want All records from 'Post' table and only matched post_id records from 'Comment' table. I know am very near to it. But not able to figure it out. Waiting for your updated answer. Thanks

Comment: One comment only to map one Post object, right? I cannot catch what you mean " All records from 'Post' table and only matched post_id records from 'Comment' table"

Comment: Or you want all comments for 1 or more Posts?

Comment: Yes , I want all comments for one post. But thanks, I have done that using your include and some extra logic from my side. Sorry for late bro

Comment: Hi, ChunTingLin, I want more help from you. Can you plz tell me how can I extract only date from "createdAt" field in parse database. Because it is giving me output like this : "Comment_Date": {
                        "__type": "Date",
                        "iso": "2016-05-25T12:45:13.730Z"
                    }, And I want only date from this array ?.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but is giving me error . I have done this as per your suggestion : var comment_date = commentResult[j].createdAt;  
                            var extract_Date =new Date(comment_date.iso)   in my commentResult[j] . and then I am printing the extract date.

Comment: Show me how you get  "Comment_Date": { "__type": "Date", "iso": "2016-05-25T12:45:13.730Z" } and the error messages.

Comment: please see the above question,  i have added in that ?